# Treat english numberals as roman during searching in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

For e-commerce search using Solr, I have product name as **Sony Alpha a7 III Mirrorless Digital Camera with 28-70mm Lens**

Most visitors search this using a keyword **sony a7 3**, where Solr is unable to find this product.

What is best way to resolve this issue? Is using synonyms for converting English numerals to Roman numerals correct way to do this?

Are there any other more better way to resolve this?

Comment: A set of synonym definitions up to 50 would probably work just fine for the content you're indexing, so I'd suggest going to quick route and just do that. Another option is to make a custom filter that does an actual conversion, but that would probably be overkill.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to solve the purpose for now. Thanks for guiding @MatsLindh